# git add patch on file with parentheses in the file path

Tags: windows, git, cmd, git-patch

I want to run `git add -p` on a file with a full path that includes parentheses, like so:

```
git add -p "(External)/Project/Filename.cs"
```

However, when I run this, I get the following error:

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
sh: -c: line 0: `git ls-files -- (External)/Project/Filename.cs'
```

I have also tried escaping the parentheses using `\`, but I get the same error. For comparison, a regular `git add` has no issues with the parentheses.

How can I pass in this file to `git add -p`?

EDIT: It seems relevant that I'm using Windows.

Comment: `git add -p "\(External\)/Project/Filename.cs"` works fine for me

Comment: @ДМИТРИЙМАЛИКОВ Using both quotes and the escape, I get "fatal: Could not switch to '\(External\)/Project': No such file or directory"

Comment: well, good luck to you and your windows!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are most likely having a problem with your shell wrongly escaping your parenthesis.

Using the following, worked for me (no need for quotes, only escaping the parenthesis with backslash):

```
git add -p \(External\)/Project/Filename.cs
```

in order to do the escaping right, I find it very helpful to use the auto-completion capabilities of bash, something like the following helps constructing the filename in a "bash-safe" way.

```
git add -p \(E[tab]...
```

if this doesn't help, you could simply try to first `cd` into "(External)/Project" and then use

```
git add -p Filename.cs
```

**UPDATE**

if you are using W32 (which is obviously the case), then i can confirm the problem.
the only workaround i found so far is to use `git gui`, which is simply a nice front-end to `git add -p` and which seems to work, even with parentheses.

Comment: @toby-allen thanks; i'm having troubles with my inline editor :-)

Comment: It's possibly relevant that I'm on Windows. FYI: I also tried `cd` into the sub-directory, but I get the exact same error message.

Comment: yes, i think this is relevant; which shell are you using? `cmd` or the "git-shell" that comes with git (and is afair a mingw-bash or some cygwin-shell)

Comment: I'm using msysgit, which uses MINGW32. I get the same results using `cmd` though.